Trying to understand public final Flux<T> subscribeOn(Scheduler scheduler, boolean requestOnSeparateThread)
In the java doc for the method its mentioned
if you are using an eager or blocking {@link Flux#create(Consumer, FluxSink.OverflowStrategy)}as the source, it can lead to deadlocks due to requests piling up behind the emitter.Thus this operator has a {@code requestOnSeparateThread} parameter, which should be set to {@code false} in this case.
Is it better to always set this as false then ? What are the disadvantages wrt to the public final Flux<T> subscribeOn(Scheduler scheduler

So for other sources it would create an unnecessary switch to another thread. Doesn't seem to be optimal for this scenario
